# how do I stop the query animation que when a nav button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

What I want: I created a sort of image gallery with a thumbnail slider and I want the thumbnails to scroll when a nav button is clicked but if the button is pushed again before the animation is completed it doesn't keep adding to the que, it clears the que and only completes the current animation.

What my problem is: When the button is clicked it puts the click animation in a que and completes all the clicks in order. Maybe someone can help we word this better.

What I have tried: I have tried adding .finish() and .stop(true, true) to my js file but I can't seem to get it working right. I'm probably putting it in the wrong spot or even using the wrong thing, I don't know and so I need some help.

Here is a functioning jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ma9j6o09/2/ 
Some of it is not working since my images are locally hosted but the slider part for the thumbnails is.

This is my function for animating the movement; what do I add to get the effect I need?

```
var clicks = 0;

    $("#right").click(function() {
       if ( clicks < 5 ) {
           clicks++;
       $("#thumbContainer").animate({
            left: "-=128px"
            }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            }); 
        }    
    });

    $("#left").click(function() {
       if (clicks > 0) {
           clicks--;
       $("#thumbContainer").animate({
            left: "+=128px"
            }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            }); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: you said " if the button is pushed again before the animation is completed it doesn't keep adding to the que" I've just test your fiddle and is working very well. After delete de script block on first line where you import AGAIN the jquery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/ma9j6o09/3/

In response to your question about `.stop()` you would use it like this:

```
$("#thumbContainer").stop(true, true).animate({
        left: "+=128px"
    }, 500, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    }); 
});
```

But this will indeed not achieve what you want as it means it will stop the animation and jump to the last frame straight away so you lose the animation you wanted.

Instead use the flag I used in the fiddle which makes it impossible to even try animate whilst an animation is in progress.

```
var clicks = 0,
    animating = false;

$("#right").click(function() {
   // Only animate if we are not already animating
   if ( clicks < 5 && !animating ) {
       animating = true;
       clicks++;
   $("#thumbContainer").animate({
        left: "-=128px"
        }, 500, function() {
            animating = false; // No longer animating
            // Animation complete.
        }); 
    }    
});

$("#left").click(function() {
   // Only animate if we are not already animating
   if (clicks > 0 && !animating) {
       animating = true;
       clicks--;
   $("#thumbContainer").animate({
        left: "+=128px"
        }, 500, function() {
            animating = false; // No longer animating
            // Animation complete.
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: That is amazing, thank you. Is there a good source for learning more about the magic you just did?

Comment: It just comes down to 6 long years of clients wanting carousels in their websites I'm afraid! Google and stackoverflow are your best friends.

Comment: Trying to get it to work on a different one but it's being stubborn, if you don't mind taking a look at it. http://codepen.io/cwilliams23/pen/DBjkC

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gkftb - You were never setting 'animating' back to false in the animation complete callback.